# Maintaining a variable throughout recursive calls in Haskell

Tags: variables, haskell, recursion

I want to calculate the following sum in Haskell: (m + i)^n from i = m to n. So far I have thought of this:

```
sum2017 m n 
|m > n = 0
|otherwise = (c + m)^n + sum2017 (m+1) n
where c = m
```

but the problem is that c changes every time due to getting assigned a new value from recursive calls

Answer (score 5):

You can stuff the actual recursion in a local function, keeping the `c` binding outside:

```
sum2017 m = go m
 where go μ n
        | μ > n     = 0
        | otherwise = (c + μ)^n + go (μ+1) n
       c = m
```

...of course, you may then omit the `c = m` entirely and just use `(m + μ)^n` in the recursion.

This specific example can also easily be done without any manual recursion at all, like

```
sum2017 m n = sum [(m+μ)^n | μ<-[m..n]]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, you want to avoid explicit recursions as much as possible.

So what do you do instead? You use looping function that does it for you ;)

```
sum2017 m n = sum $ ((^ n) . (+ m)) <$> [m .. n]
```

Or you could use lambda functions instead of this pointfree: (\x -> (c + x) ^ n)

If you decide to have a local function as leftaroundabout suggested, makes it recurse on itself, not on the global function:

```
sum2017 m = go m
  where go μ n
    | μ > n     = 0
    | otherwise = (c + μ)^n + go (μ+1) n
    c = m
```

Because otherwise, it can get out of control/memory pretty fast

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Good advice, but this answer would frankly have been better posted as a comment or edit to mine (once you have enough reputation, you can comment on other people's posts). It would be more worthwhile as a standalone answer if you elaborated on what this applicative-style mapping does. (BTW, you don't need the parens around `(^ n) . (+ m)`.)

Comment: I understand, should I delete this post and comment on yours instead?
Or add information about mapping and local-bound recursion?
(I didn't have access to comment at the time of my post, I guess I should have just refrained)